# Implicitly casting a float constant

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

Please have a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    short s;
    int i = 65696;
    float f = 65696.0F;

    printf("sizeof(short) = %lu\n", sizeof(short));

    s = i;
    printf("s = %hd\n", s);
    s = f;
    printf("s = %hd\n", s);

    s = 65696;
    printf("s = %hd\n", s);
    s = 65696.0F;
    printf("s = %hd\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

It gave output as :

```
sizeof(short) = 2
s = 160
s = 160
s = 160
s = 32767
```

In last line why it's 32767 and not 160 ? What's the difference between saying `f = 65696.0F; s = f;` and `s = 65696.0F;` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because if the integral part of the float value is not representable in the new type, the conversion is undefined behavior.

In your case, `SHRT_MAX` is probably 32767 and so the integral part of `65696.0F` is then not representable in a `short` object.

Comment: +1. Specifically, 6.3.1.4/1: *"When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined)"*

Comment: @Jon So why not same thing happening when I say `f = 65696.0F; s = f` ?

Comment: @rootkea this is undefined behavior as well and yeah undefined behavior can be unpredictive.

Comment: @Jon By 'finite value' do you mean 'a constant' ?

Comment: @rootkea no, it means neither infinities nor NaN.

Comment: @ouah Then why not behaviour is undefined when I say `s = f` ?

Comment: @rootkea It's still undefined behavior. It just happens to return `160` in your particular case.

Comment: [Info about undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) (C and C++ have identical meanings of these terms).

Answer (score 2):

This is "undefined behaviour," which means that the compiler is free to do what it wants. But "undefined" does not mean "unexplainable."

What the compiler is doing in the case of `s = f` is converting `f` first to the `int` value 65696, and then assigning 65696 to s, which overflows and leaves 160. The compiler does this because there is a CPU instruction to convert a floating point number into a 32-bit integer, but not directly into a 16-bit integer

What the compiler is doing with `s = 65696.0F` is simpler: It knows that 65696.0 is out of range, so it assigns the highest value available to `s`, which happens to be 2^15-1 = 32767.

You can verify this if you read the assembly code the compiler generates for s = f (for example using -S switch with gcc):

```
    movss   -4(%rbp), %xmm0        # Load float from memory into register xmm0
    cvttss2si       %xmm0, %eax    # Convert float in xmm0 into signed 32 bit, store in eax
    movw    %ax, -10(%rbp)         # Store lower 16 bits of eax into memory
    movswl  -10(%rbp), %eax        # Load those 16 bits into eax, with sign extend
```

The last instruction clobbers the high 16 bits of %eax, setting it to all 0s in this case.

What it generates for s = 65696.0F is simpler:

```
    movw    $32767, -10(%rbp)      # Store the lower 16 bits of 32767 into memory
    movswl  -10(%rbp), %eax        # Load those 16 bits into eax, with sign extend
```